# spark scala dataset union Dataset[Array[String]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two `Dataset[Array[String]]` .

first Dataset having records like

```
8473245,0vqt141w2d6xfmsd1,c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950,p
11117398,0vqt141w3c57bb1b1,c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950,p
329726,1141556550,c0e85ebe26e6befa568502a3c7265c34,p
601438,1149608959,ab0e30f4d904d7f6dfbd48ff7ea955d5,p
```

another dataset having records like

```
8387081,0vqt141w7h6rwq9b1,c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950,p
1194736,1243752711,c0e85ebe26e6befa568502a3c7265c34,p
```

now I want a dataset that has all the records from first dataset
and only those records from second dataset that has the 2nd field match with the first dataset.means resulting dataset should have records:

```
8473245,0vqt141w2d6xfmsd1,c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950,p
11117398,0vqt141w3c57bb1b1,c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950,p
329726,1141556550,c0e85ebe26e6befa568502a3c7265c34,p
601438,1149608959,ab0e30f4d904d7f6dfbd48ff7ea955d5,p
8387081,0vqt141w7h6rwq9b1,c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950,p
```

Comment: How big is your first dataset?

Comment: both dataset are having large number of records columns are 16.

Comment: I tried dataset1.joinWith(dataset2, dataset1("_1") === dataset2("_1") "inner"

Comment: but joinsWith is giving me Dataset([string,Array(String)] , [string,Array(String)]) . I want records as seperate records

Comment: One way to do is select the 2nd field and collect as a set. and filter the records from 2nd datasets that contains the 2nd field from that set.

Comment: in `8387081,0vqt141w7h6rwq9b1,c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950,p` 2nd field doesn't match. only third and fourth fields match

Comment: yeah thats a mistake..3rd field will match if there is 2nd field matching..

Comment: @pooja, so you are saying that 2nd and 3rd fields are to be checked and any of them matches then you merge them? how many other fields should be checked for matching?

Comment: only second is to be matched..In the output example given, 2nd is not matching for the record that comes from second dataset. it was a mistake .I thought its matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *you don't have header lines in the data I suppose you are reading data as following* (I have **used one 2nd column matching for test purpose**)

```
val dataset1 = sqlContext.read.option("header", false).csv("file1 path")
val dataset2 = sqlContext.read.option("header", false).csv("file2 path")
```

which should give you

```
dataset1
+--------+-----------------+--------------------------------+---+
|_c0     |_c1              |_c2                             |_c3|
+--------+-----------------+--------------------------------+---+
|8473245 |0vqt141w2d6xfmsd1|c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950|p  |
|11117398|0vqt141w3c57bb1b1|c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950|p  |
|329726  |1141556550       |c0e85ebe26e6befa568502a3c7265c34|p  |
|601438  |1149608959       |ab0e30f4d904d7f6dfbd48ff7ea955d5|p  |
+--------+-----------------+--------------------------------+---+
    
dataset2
+-------+-----------------+--------------------------------+---+
|_c0    |_c1              |_c2                             |_c3|
+-------+-----------------+--------------------------------+---+
|8387081|0vqt141w2d6xfmsd1|c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950|p  |
|1194736|1243752711       |c0e85ebe26e6befa568502a3c7265c34|p  |
+-------+-----------------+--------------------------------+---+
```

Following solution should work for you (*commented as explanation*)

```
//dataset2 columns to be selected
val columnsToSelect = dataset2.columns

//joining and selecting matching rows
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val matchingDataset2 = dataset1.as("table1").join(dataset2.as("table2"), col("table1._c1") === col("table2._c1"))
  .select(columnsToSelect.map(x => col("table2."+x)): _*)

//merging matching dataset2 with dataset1
dataset1.union(matchingDataset2)
```

which should give you

```
+--------+-----------------+--------------------------------+---+
|_c0     |_c1              |_c2                             |_c3|
+--------+-----------------+--------------------------------+---+
|8473245 |0vqt141w2d6xfmsd1|c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950|p  |
|11117398|0vqt141w3c57bb1b1|c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950|p  |
|329726  |1141556550       |c0e85ebe26e6befa568502a3c7265c34|p  |
|601438  |1149608959       |ab0e30f4d904d7f6dfbd48ff7ea955d5|p  |
|8387081 |0vqt141w2d6xfmsd1|c32d6691d56d27269d8d46e7e1caf950|p  |
+--------+-----------------+--------------------------------+---+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

### **Updated**

You have commented

> > Is there any way to convert org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] to Dataset[Array(String)]

You can *call a map function and change the data according to your need* as

```
dataset1.union(matchingDataset2)
  .map(row => row.toSeq.map(_.toString))
//org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Seq[String]] = [value: array<string>]
```